# ANTLR4: Erroneous input error

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

I am writing a parser for a custom script I am currently working on.

When I feed below basic script:

```
if (db.Title == 2) { }
```

which is suppose to match on `conditionStatement`. But when I run it, I get below error. The same error occur when I attempt to feed in for-loop input:

```
line 1:0 extraneous input 'if'
```

Here is my grammar:

```
grammar CustomScript;

/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

prog
    :   compoundScript EOF
    ;

compoundScript
    :  ( '{' script '}' )+
    |  ( script )
    ;

script
    :   (declaration* statement*)
    |   statement*
    ;

iterationStatement
    :   'for' '(' identifier 'in' collection ')' statement
    ;

collection
    :   list|data | identifier
    ;

statement
    :   expressionStatement
    |   conditionStatement
    |   iterationStatement
    |   '{' statement '}'
    ;

conditionStatement
    :   'if' '(' expression ')' statement ('else' statement)?
    ;

expressionStatement
    :   expression ';'?
    ;

declaration
    :   constantObjectDeclaration+
    ;

constantObjectDeclaration
    :   'set' identifier 'as' constantObject ';'?
    ;

constantObject
    :   identifier '.' identifier '[' value ']'
    ;

expression
    :   assignmentExpression
    |   expression ',' assignmentExpression
    ;

assignmentExpression
    :   postfixExpression assignmentOperator=AssignmentOperator postfixExpression    
    |   conditionalExpression
    ;

conditionalExpression
    :   logicalOrExpression ('?' expression ':' conditionalExpression)?
    ;

logicalOrExpression
    :   logicalAndExpression
    |   logicalOrExpression '||' logicalAndExpression
    ;

logicalAndExpression
    :   logicalCondition
    |   logicalAndExpression '&&' logicalCondition
    ;

postfixExpression
    :   primaryExpression       
    |   postfixExpression '[' expression ']'
    |   postfixExpression '.' Advance '.' Digits '.' identifier
    |   postfixExpression '.' Main '.' Digits '.' identifier
    |   postfixExpression '.' Split '.' Digits '.' identifier       
    |   postfixExpression '++'          // Ensure only variable++
    |   postfixExpression '--'          // Ensure only variable--
    ;

primaryExpression
    :   identifier
    |   constant
    |   stringLiteral+
    |   calcExpr                        
    |   list
    |   '(' expression ')'
    ;

calcExpr 
    :   calcExpr op=(MulDivOperator | '^') calcExpr  # MulDivExpo
    |   calcExpr op=AddSubOperator calcExpr          # AddSub
    |   number                                       # IntValue
    |   data                                         # DataValue
    |   identifier                                   # IdentifierValue
    |   constant                                     # ConstantValue
    |   '(' calcExpr ')'                             # ExprWithParens
    ;

logicalCondition
    :   data instructionOption number           # LeftDataRightNumber
    |   number instructionOption data           # LeftNumberRightData
    |   data instructionOption data             # LeftDataRightData

    |   constant instructionOption DateTime     # LeftConstantRightDateTime
    |   data instructionOption DateTime         # LeftDataRightDateTime
    |   DateTime instructionOption data         # LeftDateTimeRightData 
    |   DateTime instructionOption constant     # LeftDateTimeRightConstant

    |   data instructionOption String           # LeftDataRightString
    |   String instructionOption data           # LeftStringRightData
    |   String instructionOption constant       # LeftStringRightConstant

    |   constant instructionOption constant     # LeftConstantRightConstant
    |   constant instructionOption String       # LeftConstantRightString

    |   constant instructionOption number       # LeftConstantRightNumber
    |   number instructionOption constant       # LeftNumberRightConstant

    |   constant instructionOption data         # LeftConstantRightData
    |   data instructionOption constant         # LeftDataRightConstant

    |   identifier instructionOption constant   # LeftIdentifierRightConstant
    |   constant instructionOption identifier   # LeftConstantRightIdentifier

    |   identifier instructionOption data       # LeftIdentifierRightData
    |   data instructionOption identifier       # LeftDataRightIdentifier

    |   data In list                    # LeftDataInRightList
    |   constant In list                # LeftConstantInRightList
    |   value In list                   # LeftValueInRightList
    |   identifier In list              # LeftIdentifierInRightList

    |   '(' logicalCondition ')'        # ConditionWithParens
    ;

instructionOption
    :   Keyword | Operator | AssignmentOperator | MulDivOperator | AddSubOperator
    ;

list 
    :   ( '[' ( identifierList )? ']' )
    ;


identifierList
    :   ( identifier ','? )
    |   ( (identifier ',' )+ (identifier ','? ) )+
    ;

value 
    :   number
    |   stringLiteral
    ;

constant 
    :   (('$''{') (NonDigit | DigitsNondigits) '}')
    ;

data 
    :   identifier '.' (MetaData '.')? identifier
    ;

datetime 
    :   Quote Digits '-' Digits '-' Digits Quote
    |   Quote Digits '/' Digits '/' Digits Quote
    |   Quote Digits '-' Digits '-' Digits Space Digits ':' Digits Quote
    |   Quote Digits '/' Digits '/' Digits Space Digits ':' Digits Quote
    ;

deliveryType 
    :   Advances | Mains | Splits 
    ;

number 
    :   Digits (Dot Digits)?
    ;

Keyword
    :   Else
    |   For
    |   If
    |   Before
    |   Contains
    |   After
    |   And
    |   Or
    |   In
    |   Set
    |   StartsWith
    |   EndsWith
    ;

separator 
    :   '-' | '/' | ':'
    ;

identifier 
    :   NonDigit | DigitsNondigits
    ;

NonDigit 
    :   [a-zA-Z_]+
    ;

DigitsNondigits 
    :   [a-zA-Z0-9_]+
    ;

Digits
    :   [0-9]+
    ;

stringLiteral
    :   Quote SCharSequence? Quote
    ;

Quote 
    :   ('\"'|'\'') -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;

fragment
SCharSequence
    :   SChar+
    ;

fragment
SChar
    :   ~["\\\r\n']
    |   EscapeSequence
    ;

fragment
EscapeSequence
    :   SimpleEscapeSequence
    ;
fragment
SimpleEscapeSequence
    :   '\\' ['"?abfnrtv\\]
    ;

//fragment

AssignmentOperator
    :   '='
    |   '*='
    |   '/='
    |   '%='
    |   '+='
    |   '-='
    |   '^='
    ;

MulDivOperator
    :   '*'
    |   '/'
    ;

AddSubOperator
    :   '+'
    |   '-'
    ;

Operator
    :   '%'
    |   '&'
    |   '!'
    |   '<'
    |   '>'
    |   '=='
    |   '!='
    |   '<='
    |   '>='
    |   '&&'
    |   '||'
    |   '++'
    |   '--'
    |   ','
    ;    

/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */

Deliveries      : 'Deliveries';
Advances        : 'Advances';
Mains           : 'Mains';
Splits          : 'Splits';

Else            : 'else';
For             : 'for';
If              : 'if';
Advance         : 'Advance';
Main            : 'Main';
Split           : 'Split';
Before          : 'before';
Contains        : 'contains';
After           : 'after';
And             : 'and';
Or              : 'or';
In              : 'in';
Set             : 'Set';
StartsWith      : 'startsWith';
EndsWith        : 'endsWith';
MetaData        : 'MetaData';

//LeftParen       : '(';
//RightParen      : ')';
LeftBracket     : '[';
RightBracket    : ']';
//LeftBrace       : '{';
//RightBrace      : '}';

Less            : '<';
LessEqual       : '<=';
Greater         : '>';
GreaterEqual    : '>=';

Plus            : '+';
PlusPlus        : '++';
Minus           : '-';
MinusMinus      : '--';
Star            : '*';
Div             : '/';
Mod             : '%';

AndAnd          : '&&';
OrOr            : '||';
Caret           : '^';
Not             : '!';

Question        : '?';
Colon           : ':';
Semi            : ';';
Comma           : ',';

Assign          : '=';
StarAssign      : '*=';
ExpoAssign      : '^=';
DivAssign       : '/=';
ModAssign       : '%=';
PlusAssign      : '+=';
MinusAssign     : '-=';

Equal           : '==';
NotEqual        : '!=';
Space           : ' ' -> skip;
DoubleQuote     : '"';
Dot             : '.';

NewLine         : ('\r' '\n' ? | '\n') -> skip;
BlockComment    : '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip;

LineCommentOption1  : '//' ~[\r\n]* -> skip;
LineCommentOption2  : '#' ~[\r\n]* -> skip;

WS  :   ('\r' | '\n' | '\t') -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

## Note

Edited: Due to original expression input error issue resolved - with above grammar. Also note that the `list` expression issue `"No viable alternative input"` noted in the bounty note is also resolved with above edited grammar.

Comment: I've played a bit with your grammar and [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e4ee73d8db14dd1870c2) is some output (I personally do not consider it an answer as your grammar surely needs much more work from someone who knows much more than me -- but you might find that inspirational /or funny/). Good luck!

Comment: @vlp taking your enhancement and a little change to it - I am able to make a little head way. But some of my expressions are yielding "No viable alternative input. Example list grammar works when you provide say `a = [1]` but not when you provide `a = [1,2,3]` etc. Similarly to if condition grammar.

Comment: "No viable alternative input" issue as a result of `list` expression is resolved with edited grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Always get rid of warnings in console output. In your case:

  `warning(125): expr.g4:114:35: implicit definition of token 'DateTime' in parser
  warning(125): expr.g4:119:31: implicit definition of token 'String' in parser
  warning(125): expr.g4:234:14: implicit definition of token 'SCharSequence' in parser`

  Define all tokens explicitly (I replace DateTime with datetime).
- You can not use fragment rule in parser rule (SCharSequence). Also try to not use tokens in another tokens.
- Put keywords (if, else, for, etc.) tokens before more common toknes (id, digit, etc.).
- Try to avoid left recursion if possible (expression & assignmentExpression in your case). And use the power of EBNF wherever you can.

So, there is my corrected version of grammar, which parses your sample expression without errors:

```
grammar expr;

/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

prog
    :   compoundScript EOF
    ;

compoundScript
    :  ( '{' script '}' )+
    |  ( script )
    ;

script
    :   (declaration* statement*)
    |   statement*
    ;

iterationStatement
    :   'for' '(' identifier 'in' collection ')' statement
    ;

collection
    :   list|data | identifier
    ;

statement
    :   expressionStatement
    |   conditionStatement
    |   iterationStatement
    |   '{' statement? '}'
    ;

conditionStatement
    :   'if' '(' expression ')' statement ('else' statement)?
    ;

expressionStatement
    :   expression ';'?
    ;

declaration
    :   constantObjectDeclaration+
    ;

constantObjectDeclaration
    :   'set' identifier 'as' constantObject ';'?
    ;

constantObject
    :   identifier '.' identifier '[' value ']'
    ;

expression
    :   assignmentExpression (',' assignmentExpression)*
    ;

assignmentExpression
    :   postfixExpression assignmentOperator=AssignmentOperator postfixExpression    
    |   conditionalExpression
    ;

conditionalExpression
    :   logicalOrExpression ('?' expression ':' conditionalExpression)?
    ;

logicalOrExpression
    :   logicalAndExpression
    |   logicalOrExpression '||' logicalAndExpression
    ;

logicalAndExpression
    :   logicalCondition
    |   logicalAndExpression '&&' logicalCondition
    ;

postfixExpression
    :   primaryExpression       
    |   postfixExpression '[' expression ']'
    |   postfixExpression '.' Advance '.' Digits '.' identifier
    |   postfixExpression '.' Main '.' Digits '.' identifier
    |   postfixExpression '.' Split '.' Digits '.' identifier       
    |   postfixExpression '++'          // Ensure only variable++
    |   postfixExpression '--'          // Ensure only variable--
    ;

primaryExpression
    :   identifier
    |   constant
    |   StringLiteral+
    |   calcExpr                        
    |   list
    |   '(' expression ')'
    ;

calcExpr 
    :   calcExpr op=(MulDivOperator | '^') calcExpr  # MulDivExpo
    |   calcExpr op=AddSubOperator calcExpr          # AddSub
    |   number                                       # IntValue
    |   data                                         # DataValue
    |   identifier                                   # IdentifierValue
    |   constant                                     # ConstantValue
    |   '(' calcExpr ')'                             # ExprWithParens
    ;

logicalCondition
    :   data instructionOption number           # LeftDataRightNumber
    |   number instructionOption data           # LeftNumberRightData
    |   data instructionOption data             # LeftDataRightData

    |   constant instructionOption datetime     # LeftConstantRightDateTime
    |   data instructionOption datetime         # LeftDataRightDateTime
    |   datetime instructionOption data         # LeftDateTimeRightData 
    |   datetime instructionOption constant     # LeftDateTimeRightConstant

    |   data instructionOption StringLiteral           # LeftDataRightString
    |   StringLiteral instructionOption data           # LeftStringRightData
    |   StringLiteral instructionOption constant       # LeftStringRightConstant

    |   constant instructionOption constant     # LeftConstantRightConstant
    |   constant instructionOption StringLiteral       # LeftConstantRightString

    |   constant instructionOption number       # LeftConstantRightNumber
    |   number instructionOption constant       # LeftNumberRightConstant

    |   constant instructionOption data         # LeftConstantRightData
    |   data instructionOption constant         # LeftDataRightConstant

    |   identifier instructionOption constant   # LeftIdentifierRightConstant
    |   constant instructionOption identifier   # LeftConstantRightIdentifier

    |   identifier instructionOption data       # LeftIdentifierRightData
    |   data instructionOption identifier       # LeftDataRightIdentifier

    |   data In list                    # LeftDataInRightList
    |   constant In list                # LeftConstantInRightList
    |   value In list                   # LeftValueInRightList
    |   identifier In list              # LeftIdentifierInRightList

    |   '(' logicalCondition ')'        # ConditionWithParens
    ;

instructionOption
    :   keyword | Operator | AssignmentOperator | MulDivOperator | AddSubOperator
    ;

list 
    :   LeftBracket (dataList |  constantList | valueList |  identifierList)? RightBracket
    ;

dataList
    :   data ( Comma data )*
    ;

constantList
    :   constant ( Comma constant )*
    ;

valueList
    :   value ( Comma value )*
    ;

identifierList
    :   identifier ( Comma identifier )*
    ;

value 
    :   number
    |   StringLiteral
    ;

constant 
    :   (('$''{') (NonDigit | DigitsNondigits) '}')
    ;

data 
    :   identifier '.' (MetaData '.')? identifier
    ;

datetime 
    :   Quote Digits '-' Digits '-' Digits Quote
    |   Quote Digits '/' Digits '/' Digits Quote
    |   Quote Digits '-' Digits '-' Digits Space Digits ':' Digits Quote
    |   Quote Digits '/' Digits '/' Digits Space Digits ':' Digits Quote
    ;

deliveryType 
    :   Advances | Mains | Splits 
    ;

number 
    :   Digits (Dot Digits)?
    ;

keyword
    :   Else
    |   For
    |   If
    |   Before
    |   Contains
    |   After
    |   And
    |   Or
    |   In
    |   Set
    |   StartsWith
    |   EndsWith
    ;

separator 
    :   '-' | '/' | ':'
    ;

identifier 
    :   NonDigit | DigitsNondigits
    ;

//fragment

AssignmentOperator
    :   '='
    |   '*='
    |   '/='
    |   '%='
    |   '+='
    |   '-='
    |   '^='
    ;

MulDivOperator
    :   '*'
    |   '/'
    ;

AddSubOperator
    :   '+'
    |   '-'
    ;

Operator
    :   '%'
    |   '&'
    |   '!'
    |   '<'
    |   '>'
    |   '=='
    |   '!='
    |   '<='
    |   '>='
    |   '&&'
    |   '||'
    |   '++'
    |   '--'
    ;

/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */

Deliveries      : 'Deliveries';
Advances        : 'Advances';
Mains           : 'Mains';
Splits          : 'Splits';

Else            : 'else';
For             : 'for';
If              : 'if';
Advance         : 'Advance';
Main            : 'Main';
Split           : 'Split';
Before          : 'before';
Contains        : 'contains';
After           : 'after';
And             : 'and';
Or              : 'or';
In              : 'in';
Set             : 'Set';
StartsWith      : 'startsWith';
EndsWith        : 'endsWith';
MetaData        : 'MetaData';

//LeftParen       : '(';
//RightParen      : ')';
LeftBracket     : '[';
RightBracket    : ']';
//LeftBrace       : '{';
//RightBrace      : '}';

Less            : '<';
LessEqual       : '<=';
Greater         : '>';
GreaterEqual    : '>=';

Plus            : '+';
PlusPlus        : '++';
Minus           : '-';
MinusMinus      : '--';
Star            : '*';
Div             : '/';
Mod             : '%';

AndAnd          : '&&';
OrOr            : '||';
Caret           : '^';
Not             : '!';

Question        : '?';
Colon           : ':';
Semi            : ';';
Comma           : ',';

Assign          : '=';
StarAssign      : '*=';
ExpoAssign      : '^=';
DivAssign       : '/=';
ModAssign       : '%=';
PlusAssign      : '+=';
MinusAssign     : '-=';

Equal           : '==';
NotEqual        : '!=';
Space           : ' ' -> skip;
DoubleQuote     : '"';
Dot             : '.';

NewLine         : ('\r' '\n' ? | '\n') -> skip;
BlockComment    : '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip;

LineCommentOption1  : '//' ~[\r\n]* -> skip;
LineCommentOption2  : '#' ~[\r\n]* -> skip;

WS  :   ('\r' | '\n' | '\t') -> channel(HIDDEN);

NonDigit 
    :   [a-zA-Z_]+
    ;

Digits
    :   [0-9]+
    ;   

DigitsNondigits 
    :   [a-zA-Z0-9_]+
    ;

StringLiteral
    :   Quote SCharSequence? Quote
    ;

Quote 
    :   ('\"'|'\'') -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;

fragment SCharSequence
    :   SChar+
    ;

fragment
SChar
    :   ~["\\\r\n']
    |   EscapeSequence
    ;
fragment
EscapeSequence
    :   SimpleEscapeSequence
    ;
fragment
SimpleEscapeSequence
    :   '\\' ['"?abfnrtv\\]
    ;
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that the edited version of my grammar already parses my expressions without error. The issue in the grammar is the if statement and the for-loop. For example "given expression with if statement" ends up with "Erroneous input".

Comment: @Bitmap, I fixed grammar for your case and added new item.

Comment: Thanks @KvanTTT - matching on `expression`. Input such as `a=1, b=2, c=3` results in `extraneous input ','`. Do you know why? I have tried `expression
    :   assignmentExpression
    |   expression ( ',' assignmentExpression ) 
    ;` still no job ):

Comment: @Bitmap, your declare Comma (',') in Operator and in Token. So I removed it from Operator and now it works.

Comment: I extended ``conditionStatement` to `conditionStatement
    :   'if' '(' expression ')' statement  ('else if' statement)? ('else' statement)?
    ;`. The else-if doesn't work do you know why?

Comment: Could you please add your code for parsing? But I've already seen that ```else if``` should be separated: ```else``` ```if``` (they are different tokens).

Comment: I haven't started working on the parser code - just want the grammar to work first. When you say it should be separated do you mean something like this `conditionStatement
    : (
  'if' '(' expression ')' statement  ('else if' statement)?
  |   'if' '(' expression ')' statement  ('else' statement)?
  | 'if' '(' expression ')' statement  ('else if' statement)? ('else' statement)?
 )
    ;`

Comment: No :) Wrong word: 'else if'. There are two tokens 'else' and 'if', not one.

Comment: I have I changed `statement` to this: `expressionStatement? conditionStatement iterationStatement? | iterationStatement? conditionStatement expressionStatement? | conditionStatement? iterationStatement expressionStatement? | expressionStatement? iterationStatement conditionStatement? | conditionStatement? expressionStatement iterationStatement?`. This gives me the flexibility to construct complex syntax but extremely slow in generating the syntax tree. Do you know why?

Comment: Could you please create another question with full grammar code or contact me on email?

Comment: The grammar is the same. I can contact you via email if you like?! what is your addr?

Comment: I have dropped you a message ;-) Also edit your e addr to avoid spammers.